# Is there a way to use Flow types in Codepen?

Tags: codepen

I write statically typed javascript with [Flow](https://flow.org/), but that doesn't seem to work in [Codepen](https://codepen.io). Is there a way to add custom babel plugins in the pipeline, like for example **transform-flow-strip-types** which would do the trick?